# Nutch 2.3.1 hangs while running inject

Tags: hbase, nutch

Nutch 2.3.1 hangs while running inject command.

```
./nutch inject seed/

InjectorJob: starting at 2016-10-04 11:03:52 
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: seed
```

Nothing happens after this & no exception are available in logs. Please suggest to make it work.